# How can I get OS X's Dynamic DNS client to register a local IP address?

Tags: macos, network, dns, bonjour

Background: I'm essentially re-creating Back To My Mac.

I have a VPN set-up on my VPS, handing out addresses in the `10.x.y.0/24` range, with BIND running and accessible at `10.x.y.1`.

There's a zone named `xyz` with updates enabled. The SOA/NS records for `xyz` indicate a globally-resolvable name, `dns.xyz-public.com`, which resolves to `10.x.y.1`.  (i.e. the address can only contacted within the VPN.)

When I configure Dynamic DNS (through Sharing: "Use dynamic global hostname"), I set my hostname to `mylaptop.xyz`, set credentials, and voilà; `mylaptop` appears in the zone!

... only, it's added with the IP address as seen by the public internet, not as seen in the VPN.  I had assumed that, given the DNS update was happening via a local address, the IP address that corresponded would be used, but it would appear OS X is determining its own public IP address itself before publishing it to DNS.

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: I've realised there's a workaround/hack: I'm replacing BIND anyway (because it doesn't support DNS-LLQ/DNS-UL on non-OS X), so I could just have it ignore the A record's payload published by clients and replace it with the source address of the UDP packet.

Comment: If you found an answer please post it as an answer with some background explanation and not as a comment so I can up-vote it ;-)

Comment: @klanomath: it's not an answer, it's a hack extremely specific to my circumstances (which would apply to no-one actually wanting an answer to this question). People do not typically replace BIND with a custom implementation.